# Regular Expression to get Information from Whatsapp Text file

Tags: java, regex

I have no idea about creating regular expressions for extracting different text from a text file. I am working on text file consisting of message details in whatsapp chat.

Consider the following data from a text file of whatsapp chat:

```
25/12/2012 9:15 am: User1: Faith makes all things possible,
Hope makes all things work,
Love makes all things beautiful,
May you have all the three for this Christmas.
MERRY CHRISTMAS
01/01/2013 12:03 am: User1: <message>.
04/08/2013 10:54 am: User2: Happy Friendship day
13/10/2013 11:57 am: User1:<message>
<message continues>
<message continues>
30/12/2013 10:07 pm: User3:<message>
30/12/2013 11:12 pm: User4: Same to you
```

This is a sample chat text from which I need to extract Date, Time, Username, Message. I am working in java for this.
The java code for this that I have worked out is as follows.But Didnt found any correct REGEX according to my requirement.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text filepath"));
String sCurrentLine;
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(REGEX); //REGEX required for extracting data
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
Matcher m = r.matcher(sCurrentLine);

if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println("Date: " + m.group(1) );
  System.out.println("Time: " + m.group(2) );
  System.out.println("User: " + m.group(3) );
  System.out.println("Message: " + m.group(4) );
} else {
  System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you made any attempts at creating the required regex?

Comment: @Ondkloss I have tried this : ^(\\d\\d?[\\/-]\\d\\d?[\\/-]\\d{2,4}) (\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d)(?: [ap]m)?: ([^:]+): (.*)$ and this : (([A-Za-z]{1,3}\\s[0-9]{1,2},\\s[0-9]{1,2}[:]{1}[0-9]{1,2}\\s[APM]{2})|([A-Za-z]{1,3}\\s[0-9]{1,2},\\s[0-9]{1,4},\\s[0-9]{1,2}[:]{1}[0-9]{1,2}\\s[APM]{2}))\\s-\\s(.*):\\s([\\s\\S]*)

Comment: Excellent! Next time please include it in your question to better understand what you've attempted (and perhaps why that approach didn't work).

Comment: Ok.I will keep it in mind. @Ondkloss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this regex,

```
(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s(\d(?:\d)?:\d{2} [ap]m):\s([^:]*):(.*?)(?=\s*\d{2}\/|$)
```

Java regex would be,

```
"(?s)(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4})\\s(\\d(?:\\d)?:\\d{2} [ap]m):\\s([^:]*):(.*?)(?=\\s*\\d{2}/|$)"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vC2yW4/10)